# How to add avro.schema.url to hive partition storage information?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying command

```
ALTER TABLE mytable PARTITION(date='2010-02-22')  SET 'avro.schema.url' 
'hdfs://xxx.com:9000/location/to/my/schema/_schema.avsc';
```

But it is returning parsing Error :

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:49 cannot recognize input near 'SET' 
>       ''avro.schema.url'' ''hdfs://xxx.com:9000/location/to/my/schema/_schema.avsc'' in alter
>   table partition statement suffix

Answer (score 2):

This is right syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable PARTITION(date='2010-02-22')  SET TBLPROPERTIES( 
'avro.schema.url' 
'hdfs://xxx.com:9000/location/to/my/schema/_schema.avsc');
```